# Android OpenGL ES 2.0: Invalid Vertex Shader. Link Cannot Proceed

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

This is the best I can do with obtaining the debug errors.

[image: snapshot]
[Link for a larger image version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unXMS.png)

As you can see, glGetProgramInfoLog() returns the following sentence:

*"Invalid vertex shader. Link cannot proceed."*

The yellow line in the Eclipse IDE is the code line where the program had just executed, via stepping-over. The green line with an arrow pointing it is where the program will execute.

I would prefer it if it tells me what line my vertex shader code is wrong at, or something that points me in a good direction. With this vague description, I can only ask you for help.

The vertex shader code looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_mvMatrix;
uniform vec3 u_lightPosition;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec3 a_normal;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_mvMatrix * a_position);
    vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(u_mvMatrix * vec4(a_normal, 0.0));

    float distance = length(u_lightPosition - modelViewVertex);
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_lightPosition - modelViewVertex);
    float diffuse = max(dot(modelViewNormal, lightVector), 0.1);
    diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (0.25 * distance * distance));

    v_color = a_color * diffuse;

    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * a_position;
}
```

I don't know where I did wrong. Can you help me find it? If you need more info, I'll add them. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

There is no debug info from glGetShaderInfo().

[image: glGetShaderInfo() gives nothing.]
[Larger version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aT4s.png)

Even more info:

[image: String is empty.]

**EDIT 2:**

Tried a combination of glGetShader() and glGetShaderInfo(), still no luck.

[image: Mixed glGetShader() and glGetShaderInfo() outputs.]
[Larger version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6hHM.png)

Comment: Did you check that the shader compiles successfully? Post that part of the code.

Comment: It's already posted. It's already included in the question. It compiles just fine.

Comment: Is it because the Imgur image is too low-res?

Comment: It's not there, you aren't checking if the shader compiles, at least for the code pasted here. Use glGetShader and glGetShaderInfoLog to check the compile status and compilation infolog.

Comment: Updated. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error!

Of all this time, I was editing the wrong source file!

Kept saving/checking/saving/checking..., I didn't realize that the source code shown above isn't included in the project, therefore the program stating that my vertex shader is invalid, is because the compiler is compiling the source code with an empty vertex shader, and not the newly-modified version (which is the source code I was editing this whole time).

I'm so sorry to waste everybody's time.